# LED dimming circuit

Tags: led, resistors, dimming

I have a [MeanWell IDLV-65A](https://www.meanwell-web.com/en-gb/ac-dc-constant-voltage-led-driver-cv-input-range-idlv--65a--12)-12 LED driver that I would like to control brightness via the 0-10 VDC dimming circuit.  [Spec sheet here](https://www.meanwell-web.com/content/files/pdfs/productPdfs/MW/IDLV-65/IDLV-65-spec.pdf).

I have a basic understanding of electrical circuits, and successfully dimmed similar drivers using an external 10 VDC power source.  But this time, I need to do so without an external source.  Note this "A-Type" model has an unregulated auxiliary DC output (last page of spec sheet) that may be useful for this.

I tried connecting a 100K logarithmic potentiometer as a series resistor (only two terminals) between DIM+ and DIM-.  That works fairly well for dimming, going down to minimal brightness.  The problem is this does not achieve 100% brightness; 100K ohm causes dimming.  I tested a variety of fixed resistors between DIM+ and DIM- in series, and found even 10 M ohm still causes dimming.

First Question: Am I correct to conclude that simply introducing resistance to the dimming circuit is not how it should be used?  Rather that a voltage must be introduced between DIM+ and DIM-?

Second Question: Is it safe to use the auxiliary VDC output to drive the dimming circuit?  Specifically I would connect the potentiometer as a voltage divider; potentiometer outer pins to AUX+ and AUX- (0.12 mA current in AUX circuit), potentiometer center pin to DIM+, AUX- to DIM-.  I should also be able to swap the CW/CCW control by alternatively center pin to DIM-, and AUX+ to DIM+.

This seems correct to me, but I'm asking for confirmation and advice before I ruin an expensive driver.  Thanks for the help :).

Comment: The spec sheet says to use a voltage source. You are using a resistor. Why do you think this will work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a real voltage source for dimming, so just a potentiometer is not enough. A floating input might see an unpredictable voltage and that's why it seemed to work. But as you have the A-type it's fairly easy: as you suggested you can use the auxiliary output as voltafe source for your potentiometer. To be save you can add a high-side series resistor to divide the Vaux (~12V) to the required 10V, but I doubt that leaving this step would actually harm the device.

Comment: I did exactly as you suggested with the 100 K log pot, and it worked perfectly.  Decent full-range dimming control, and full brightness.